# Compile error combining groovy and java (using maven)

Tags: java, maven, groovy

I want to use groovy for my domain object to get rid of boilerplate code of setter/getters and so on.
But I have a issue with using AST transformations, particularly with generated constructors.

Here some minimum code for reproduction:

### App.java

```
package experiment.groovy;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Example example = new Example("Alex");
        System.out.println(example.getName());
    }
}
```

### Example.groovy

```
package experiment.groovy

import groovy.transform.Canonical

@Canonical
class Example {
    String name;
    int id;
}
```

### Project structure

[image]

### pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation=
"http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>experiment.groovy</groupId>
    <artifactId>groovy-ast</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
                <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generateStubs</goal>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>generateTestStubs</goal>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I also tried with `groovy-eclipse-compiler`:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <compilerId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</compilerId>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                    <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</artifactId>
                    <version>2.8.0-01</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                    <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-batch</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1.8-01</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

And `mvn compile` failing with error.

```
1. ERROR in C:\DEV\Groovy\src\main\java\experiment\groovy\ZApp.java (at line 5)
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
    Example example = new Example("ToDelete");
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[ERROR] Found 1 error and 0 warnings.
The constructor Example(String) is undefined
```

So the question is: what should I change, OR, may be, it is impossible?

P.S. In future, if it is important, I will add `javax.persistence.Entity` annotation to the Example class.

Comment: Tim, I updated the post

Comment: It's suggested to put both `java` and `groovy` sources under `src/main/groovy` :/ Tried?

Comment: Just tried, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I'd ask about this on the Groovy user [mailing list](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Mailing+Lists).  I think the issue is that the Java stub generated contains getters and setters for 'id' and 'name', but doesn't include the constructors from the AST.  I'm not sure whether that's a bug or a known limitation.  But I thought things like this were supposed to work, so I'm leaning more towards the former.

Edit: This obviously wouldn't apply to the Groovy-Eclipse plugin for Maven since it doesn't use stubs.  I don't know enough about it to say what might cause this there.

Edit 2: I couldn't contain my curiosity.  I've gone ahead and [asked](http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/Canonical-Stubs-td5719971.html) on the mailing list.

Edit 3: See Guillaume's answer [here](http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/Canonical-Stubs-tp5719971p5719976.html).  Basically the Java stubs are generated before the AST transformation has been applied, so Java isn't able to see the constructors @Canonical added.  Your solution works because it's tying Java to the class file, not the stub.  An alternative would be to use the [Groovy-Eclipse Compiler Plugin for Maven](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy-Eclipse+compiler+plugin+for+Maven).

Answer (score 0):

The only way I figure out: divide groovy and java into separate maven modules, and java module will have dependency to groovy module.

The structure of the project will be like this:
[image: Java Groovy project structure]

### Parent pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
                             http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>experiment.groovy</groupId>
    <artifactId>groovy-ast</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <modules>
        <module>Groovy</module>
        <module>Java</module>
    </modules>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <distributionManagement>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>repoId</id>
            <url><!-- Url of your snapshot repository --></url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>
</project>
```

### Groovy module pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                             http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>groovy-ast</artifactId>
        <groupId>experiment.groovy</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>groovy-code</artifactId>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <compilerId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</compilerId>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                        <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</artifactId>
                        <version>2.8.0-01</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                        <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-batch</artifactId>
                        <version>2.1.8-01</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
    <!--
    This plugin is important, because without
    <extensions>true</extensions> no files will be compiled.
    See http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy-Eclipse+compiler+plugin+for+Maven
    -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.0-01</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

### Java module pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                             http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>groovy-ast</artifactId>
        <groupId>experiment.groovy</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>java-code</artifactId>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>experiment.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-code</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

If your groovy code will depend on some Java code, then to avoid circular dependency you should extract interfaces that will be used in Java and Groovy code to separate module.

See here more info: http://groovy.codehaus.org/Mixed+Java+and+Groovy+Applications

**UPDATE**
To easy use entities from separate artifact you could add a maven-dependency-plugin to unpack specific dependency: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/unpacking-artifacts.html

Answer (score -1):

I faced with the same issue and here is my solution:

[image: Project structure]

### On the picture you can see my project structure:

- post-box-data-server (**parent project**)
- post-server (**child project**)

---

### post-box-data-server's pom.xml:

```
<properties>
    <groovy-all.version>2.4.14</groovy-all.version>
     ...
    <!--for <build>-->
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.7.0</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
    <groovy-eclipse-compiler.version>2.9.2-04</groovy-eclipse-compiler.version>
    <groovy-eclipse-batch.version>2.4.14-01</groovy-eclipse-batch.version>
     ...
</properties>
```

Pay attention to the **2.4.14** in two properties it's Groovy version and ***it must be the same for both!***

The `<dependencyManagement>` section:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        ...
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
        <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
        <version>${groovy-all.version}</version>
     </dependency>
         ...
   </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

The `<build>` section:

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>

          <configuration>
            <source>${java.version}</source>
            <target>${java.version}</target>
            <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
            <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
            <verbose>true</verbose>
            <compilerId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</compilerId>
          </configuration>

          <dependencies>
            <dependency>
              <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
              <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</artifactId>
              <version>${groovy-eclipse-compiler.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
              <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
              <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-batch</artifactId>
              <version>${groovy-eclipse-batch.version}</version>
            </dependency>
          </dependencies>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

**As a supplement**, if you are going to use the latest versions of the org.codehaus libraries you have to add their repository in the pom.xml:

```
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>bintray</id>
      <name>Groovy Bintray</name>
      <url>https://dl.bintray.com/groovy/maven</url>
      <releases>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
```

---

### post-server's pom.xml:

The `<dependencies>` section:

```
<dependencies>
     ...
    <dependency>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
          <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    ...
</dependencies>
```

The `<build>` section:

```
<build>
   ...
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
   ...
</build>
```