# Calling a @Canonical Groovy POGO constructor inside Java code

Tags: java, groovy

Given this Groovy domain class (for persistence in MongoDB):

```
@Canonical
class Counter {
    @Id String id
    String name
    long count = 0
    Date createdTimestamp = new Date()
    Date updatedTimestamp = new Date()
}
```

Since only 'name' need be supplied when creating a new Counter, is there a way to call the @Canonical-generated map-based constructors, as the Groovy approach below will not compile in Java:

```
// Invalid Java code
counterRepository.save(new Counter(name: newCounterName));
```

Must I either use the implicit setter:

```
// Valid, but a bit verbose, Java code
Counter counter = new Counter();
counter.setName(newCounterName);
counterRepository.save(counter);
```

Or create a static factory method in the Counter POGO:

```
static Counter init(String newCounterName) {
    return new Counter(name: newCounterName)
}
```

Enabling the following:

```
// Valid, concise, but perhaps/hopefully redundant?
counterRepository.save(Counter.init(counterName));
```

The last approach is the one currently used.

Comment: Are you creating an instance of this groovy domain class in java?

Comment: Yes, I am creating an instance of the Groovy class inside a Java-based Spring MVC @RestController

Comment: From the docs: *Tuple-style constructors are provided which allow you to set properties in the same order as they are defined.* So if the change the order of `id` and `name` there's a chance to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you don't really want to use `@Cannonical`, you are more after `@TupleConstructor`. With this AST you can specify fields you want to use and have more fine grained controller over the constructor. An example could be:

```
@TupleConstructor(includes=['name'])
class Counter {
  @Id String id
  String name
  long count = 0
  Date createdTimestamp = new Date()
  Date updatedTimestamp = new Date()
}
```

For more see http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/transform/TupleConstructor.html

Comment: The `@Canonical` annotation also applies a tuple constructor (as well as equals and hashcode).

Comment: I don't think this answers the question - at least, not for me: I don't currently have a solution. As @cjstehno mentions, `@Canonical` implies `@TupleConstructor`, and adding an explicit attribute as shown doesn't seem to help. The issue seems to be that the Groovy `@TupleConstructor` transformation isn't applied in a way that Java source code can use it from the same jar. See also this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23805576